# problem on creating new document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to add a new document with mongoose
but it just creates only the _id without all the details I entered
in the postman i entered:
{
"name":"jhon",
"email":"jhon11@gmail",
"password":"1234"
}
but got this in the res:
{
"_id": "6072e8d3f0f69037cc05b8cb",
"__v": 0
}

my code:

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
try {
    let user = new User(req.body)
    await user.save()
    res.send(user)

}
catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(`error ${error}`)
}
```

}

and the schema is:

```
const userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    Type:String
},
email:{
    Type:String
},
password:{
    Type:String,
}
```

})

thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should check the `req.body` value, the schema validation fails and that's why an "empty" document is created. this means `req.body` does not contains  the structure you expect.

Comment: Can I see your entire file where you starting your express app? You're probably missing app.use(express.json()) before actual route.

Answer (score 0):

Postman isn't very straight forward in explaining how it sends out post requests. I'm saying this because I also had some run-downs with it. It is most likely sending out an empty body in the request. Open up postman again, and go to the post request you created. We already know your request reached the backend server, so it means the url is fine, and that its type is in fact a post request. So now, click on the **Body** tab.
I'm gonna go ahead and guess you chose the *raw* option amongst the million available options there, correct?
In the textarea zone, insert your raw json again, as you did before:

```
{
    "name":"jhon",
    "email":"jhon11@gmail",
    "password":"1234"
}
```

But wait! before sending that out, look to the right. There's a combo-box there. A dropdown. A select menu (whatever you wanna call it).
By default, postman chooses TEXT as the default option. Change it to JSON!
**NOW IT'S GONNA WORK!**

Also, maybe before sending that out for test spin, i'd recommend putting a console.log in bewtween your lines and see what prints out, like so:

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
try {
    let user = new User(req.body)
    console.log('req.body is:', req.body)
    await user.save()
    res.send(user)

}
catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(`error ${error}`)
}
```

If your req.body is still being presented as empty, then my next question to you would be: Are you using bodyParser on your server? Because could also be the case. Body parser, as its name suggests, is meant for dealing with req.body, so it could actually be readable. try adding a body parser to your express server.

Good luck!
I hope that helps.